# Powershell issue with using variable as a parameter in argument

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a script, that will unlock a user on all organization domain controllers.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

Write-Host "Tool for unlocking user on all Domain Controllers" -ForegroundColor Green

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$testform = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$testform.Text = 'Account Unlock Tool'
$testform.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(250,200)
$testform.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$okb = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okb.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25,130)
$okb.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
$okb.Text = 'Unlock'
$okb.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$testform.AcceptButton = $okb
$testform.Controls.Add($okb)

$test = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$test.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(125,130)
$test.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
$test.Text = 'close'
$test.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$testform.AcceptButton = $test
$testform.Controls.Add($test)

$lb = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$lb.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,40)
$lb.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240,20)
$lb.Text = 'Please enter the username in text box:'
$testform.Controls.Add($lb)

$tb = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$tb.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(40,80)
$tb.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$testform.Controls.Add($tb)
$testform.Topmost = $true
$testform.Add_Shown({$tb.Select()})
$rs = $testform.ShowDialog()

$name = $tb.Text

$Sites = @('BXDC01.DOMAIN.org'.'NJDC01.DOMAIN.org','BXDC02.DOMAIN.org','BXDC03.DOMAIN.org','NJDC02.DOMAIN.org','NJAD01.DOMAIN.org','LMBAD02.DOMAIN.org','BXAD01.DOMAIN.org','HQDC01.DOMAIN.org')

foreach ($index in $Sites) {

    $index
    Unlock-ADAccount -Identity ($name) -Server $index
    
}
```

I am running into this issue:

```
Unlock-ADAccount : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Server'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\Users\jdewolf\Downloads\DCAccountUnlocker.ps1:60 char:45
     Unlock-ADAccount -Identity ($name) -Server $index
                                                ~~~~~~
     CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Unlock-ADAccount], ParameterBindingValidationException
     FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.UnlockADAccount
```

`$index` outputs the server if. I comment out the unlock line and just output the value. I am not sure why it is `null` when used in the argument?

Comment: You have a dot instead of a comma between the first and second element in the array $sites

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a simple *typo*, but the resulting symptom is subtle:

In `'BXDC01.DOMAIN.org'.'NJDC01.DOMAIN.org'`, **replace `.` with `,`** given that you mean these two hostnames to be *separate array elements*.

As for the symptom:

- `'BXDC01.DOMAIN.org'.'NJDC01.DOMAIN.org'` is interpreted as wanting to access a *property* literally named `NJDC01.DOMAIN.org` on the (literal) `[string]` instance `'BXDC01.DOMAIN.org'`
- Given that a `[string]` instance has no such property, PowerShell quietly defaults to returning `$null`

  - Note that if [`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) `-Version 2` or higher were in effect, it would instead report a statement-terminating *error*.
- The `$null` value therefore becomes part of the array and is enumerated by the `foreach` statement. Thus, in the first iteration `$index` is `$null`, causing the error you saw.

Comment: I love it when it's easy! Thank you so much for not only pointing out the issue but also explaining what is going in. I really appreciate that :)

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @JuneAtalanta; my pleasure.